# Привязать поддомен к порту

Tags: node.js, dns, amazon, port

У меня есть домен (`domen.ru`), он привязан к ip (`ip`) моего хостинга на амазоне, у домена есть 2 поддомена (`subdomen1`, `subdomen2`), у меня открыты два порта (`port1`, `port2`). На хостинге стоит два сервера NodeJs (`nodejs1` на порте `port1`, `nodejs2` на порте `port2`). Мне **обязательно** нужно, чтобы когда человек набирает в браузере адрес `subdomen1.domen.ru`, запрос шел на порт `port1` (Соответсвенно, чтобы его получал сервер `nodejs1`), а если он набирает `subdomen2.domen.ru` - `port2` и `nodejs2`, если же он набирает просто `domen.ru`, он не должен попадать на один и этих nodejs серверов. Мне **желательно** нужно, чтобы при наборе `domen.ru:port1` или `domen.ru:port2` человек не попадал на один из серверов nodejs.

Comment: Очень подозреваю что ваша задача не имеет решения без использования прокси

Answer (score 1):

ситуация абсолютно типовая. и есть абсолютно типовое решение: использование т.н. [«обратного прокси»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8).

1. настраиваете свои программы на прослушивание только локального адреса (часто используют `127.0.0.1`)
2. устанавливаваете какой-нибудь «обратный прокси» (наиболее популярные: [*nginx*](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) и [*apache*](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html)).
3. настраиваете «обратный прокси» на проксирование нужных запросов к нужным локальным прогаммам.